# I'm having trouble with the prototype part in Figma

Tags: figma

I was prototyping for my wireframes in figma. I want the navigation part to stay fixed at the bottom of the screen and I want to be able to scroll the screen and see my other content. Does anyone know how to do this? I would be very happy if you can help

The screens I designed in the figma are a little long and the navigation part is at the bottom. I'm having trouble scouring the screen down so that I can see the navigation part, but the navigation part I want stays at the bottom of my prototype screen and I scroll through the other contents on the screen.

I tried to make a responsive design